# How to use this js script in Angular: have I got to create a service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create a small IoT project with an external bluetooth sensor. I'm using SensorTag by TI and I have a couple of js library to manage it.

At this moment I'm using a simple HTML page with some js code, I want to move my project to Ionic Framework using Angular.

```
<script>
  // Globals.
  var sensortag
  var values;
  var compensationX = 0;
  var compensationY = 0;

  function initialise()
  {
    initialiseSensorTag()
  }

  function initialiseSensorTag()
  {
    // Create SensorTag CC2650 instance.
    sensortag = evothings.tisensortag.createInstance(
      evothings.tisensortag.CC2650_BLUETOOTH_SMART)

    // Set up callbacks and sensors.
    sensortag
      .statusCallback(statusHandler)
      .errorCallback(errorHandler)
      .keypressCallback(keypressHandler)
      .accelerometerCallback(accelerometerHandler, 100)
  }

  function connect()
  {
    sensortag.connectToNearestDevice()
  }

  function disconnect()
  {
    sensortag.disconnectDevice()
    displayStatus('Disconnected')
  }

  function statusHandler(status)
  {
    displayStatus(status)

    if (evothings.tisensortag.ble.status.SENSORTAG_ONLINE == status)
    {
      // displaySprite()
    }
  }

  function errorHandler(error)
  {
    if (evothings.easyble.error.DISCONNECTED == error)
    {
      displayStatus('Disconnected')
      // sprite.hide()
    }
    else
    {
      displayStatus('Error: ' + error)
    }
  }

  function keypressHandler(data)
  {
    compensationX = values.x;
    compensationY = values.y;

  }

  function accelerometerHandler(data)
  {
    values = sensortag.getAccelerometerValues(data);
    var rawX = values.x; 
    var rawY = values.y;
    var degreeX = rawX - compensationX;
    var degreeY = rawY - compensationY;

  }


  document.addEventListener(
    'deviceready',
    function() { evothings.scriptsLoaded(initialise) },
    false)
  </script>
```

My idea is to create a service, but I cannot figure how to manage addEventListener and also the initialization.
I begin whit this code:

```
app.factory('SensorFactory', function(){

    var sensortag
    var values;
    var compensationX = 0;
    var compensationY = 0;

    return {
        initialiseSensorTag: function(){
            sensortag = evothings.tisensortag.createInstance(
          evothings.tisensortag.CC2650_BLUETOOTH_SMART)

        // Set up callbacks and sensors.
        sensortag
          .statusCallback(statusHandler)
          .errorCallback(errorHandler)
          .keypressCallback(keypressHandler)
          .accelerometerCallback(accelerometerHandler, 100)
        }  

        connect: function(){
        sensortag.connectToNearestDevice()
      }
    }               
});
```

But I have two question:

1) how can I manage this part of the js:

```
document.addEventListener(
    'deviceready',
    function() { evothings.scriptsLoaded(initialise) },
    false)
```

2) I can I keep the sensor values (values) into my app scope? I need them for my app.

Comment: what have you tried so far? at the moment, there is no angular at all in this code.

Comment: @Claies I'm trying, I want to know if a service if is a good way to wrap this javascript function

Comment: well, that's not a very specific question.  usually yes or no answers aren't very useful.

Comment: @Claies I add also the first piece of the service I create with my specific questions

Answer (score 0):

For the deviceready piece use a scope.on($viewContentLoaded, $stateChangeSuccess) or other built in listener that fits your needs instead.